# What do I need to know in order to undersrtand I/O Completion Ports?

Tags: c++, multithreading, sockets, io

Sorry for this stupid question :-)

I discovered that the best way to handle hundreds (or even thousands) of socket connections is to use I/O Completion Ports, but I am having a hard time understanding the tutorials for this subject. My question is what topics I should understand first before actually understanding I/O Completion Ports? The only topic I can think of is thread pools, anything else?

Comment: There isn't really anything that can be said to make you understand it. I guess someone explaining it would help. As for that, what language are you using?

Comment: @Evan Carslake I mean what prerequisites I should already know before actually start studying this subject. I am using C++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say you would need to understand:

1. How the traditional *poll*/*readiness* model works (This is not intended for IOCP in itself, which is entirely different, but since the vast majority of socket I/O is performed using the former, differentiating, and specifically *avoiding* semantics of the former is useful).
2. Why IOCP is better than the poll model; how does it differ and what does it bring to the table
3. The concept of *ownership*. IOCP relies on the fact that it can own memory throughout the duration of a given operation.
4. Queuing or pending I/O operations, and dealing asynchronously with queues
5. Callbacks